# Java reflection isAccessible method

Tags: java, reflection

I'm learning reflection. When I execute the following code:

```
package main;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {

        Base firstBase = new Base();
        Field firstBaseField = firstBase.getClass().getDeclaredField("protectedBuffer");
        System.out.println(firstBaseField.isAccessible());

    }
}
```

This is Base class:

```
package main;

public class Base {

    private StringBuffer buffer;
    protected StringBuffer protectedBuffer;
    public StringBuffer buffer2;

}
```

the result is false. But shoudn't it be true, because I can access `protectedBuffer` in this way: `firstBase.protectedBuffer`?

Comment: I know that I just was writing String and somehow it autocompletes StringBuffer . It is not important what is the class in this case.

Comment: Instead of the `firstBaseField.isAccessible()` check, you may want `(firstBaseField.getModifiers() & (Modifier.PROTECTED | Modifier.PRIVATE)) == 0`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is because you are not testing whether Field `protectedBuffer` is accessible when you do `firstBaseField.isAccessible();`

What happens here is that you check value of `AccessibleObject` which is the base class for Field.
This flag doesn't tell you if field is accessible by java access modifiers, it tells you whether these modifiers are currently ignored.

When you get false on `firstBaseField.isAccessible()` it simply means that java access rules are still in place and are not overriden by reflection mechanisms.

**setAccessible()**

> Set the accessible flag for this object to the indicated boolean value. A value of true indicates that the reflected object should suppress Java language access checking when it is used. A value of false indicates that the reflected object should enforce Java language access checks.

**Edit**

To test if the field is accessible by java access modifiers, you could try to access it and catch `IllegalAccessException`, like in example bellow.

```
Field field = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField("someField");
//  IllegalAccessException
field.get(instance);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I read about accesible, but I forget it for the moment when I post the question. So is there a way to understand is the field accesible directly (i.e. with firstBaseField.variable). It's not important for me now, I am just curious.

Comment: You can use method Field.getModifiers() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getModifiers--and then check if the modifier you are looking at is public: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html

Comment: Actually, the simplest way would be to try and access the field. If you cannot access it, IllegalAccessExceptionwill be thrown. This will cover protected and package private case as well.

Comment: this is the best way I think. Maybe there isn't such method and your way is working in the way I want. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You wrongly understand this accessible flag. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html) when accessible is true, all the access checks are bypassed (you can use this field or method and Java will not check whether it's public or not). When accessible is false, the access checks work. And as it's written in documentation, it's `false` by default for *any* `AccessibleObject` (even for `public` fields or methods).

Answer (score 5):

As of Java 9 the `isAccessible` method is deprecated. You can use `canAccess` instead.

Comment: I would love to upvote but had to downvote b/c as as reader i can only guess you're referring to a method in [AccessibleObject](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html). If you could provide a brief code snippet showing how the OP's code could be made to work with this, i'd surely upvote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all `Fields` retrieved using `Class#getDeclaredField(String name)` have the `accessible` flag set to **false**. You would also get false for the `public` field `buffer2`.

The `Field` class is a subclass of [`AccessibleObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html):

> By default, a reflected object is *not* accessible.